# How to check for empty pages and HTTPErrors in ruby webcrawler

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This code randomly grabs an image from google images. However, I get errors when the webcrawler tries to search for a term which google shows no results for. I also get errors when google gives the webcrawler of an image which no longer exists. How could I write this code so that if it encounters an error it would rerun and try to fetch another image.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + rand(0-999999).to_s + "&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.dmg&biw=1354&bih=622&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=sNEfUf-fHvLx0wG7uoG4DQ"
googim = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
googimstr = googim.to_s
durl = googim.to_s.split('imgurl=')[1].split('&amp')[0]

name = durl.reverse.split("/")[0].reverse

open("./data/images/#{name}", 'wb') do |file|
          file << open(durl).read
end
```

and here are the two types of errors I receive

First Error:

```
usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:353:in `open_http': 400 Bad Request (OpenURI::HTTPError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:708:in `buffer_open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:688:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
    from wc.rb:11:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'
    from wc.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Second Error:

```
wc.rb:6:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from wc.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the appropriate portion of your code in a `begin/end` block and `rescue` the exception.  For example:

```
begin
  open("./data/images/#{name}", 'wb') do |file|
    file << open(durl).read
  end
rescue => e
  puts "some failure: #{e}"
end
```

Here's a link to the Exceptions, Catch, and Throw chapter of Pickaxe/Programming Ruby: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html

Comment: *edit, works fine, I just added the whole code within after the begin and then it catches all the errors. Is there anyway I can loop back to the begin if an error is found?

Comment: Check out `retry`.  http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-retry